# Telerik MVC - Numeric textbox in grid editor

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, telerik-grid, telerik-mvc

In my editor for insert telerik show only common textbox (not integer,decimal etc).

this is my view:

```
@(Html.Telerik().Grid <GamePlayer2>(Model).Name("za11").DataKeys(keys => keys.Add(c => c.Id))
.ToolBar(commands => commands.Insert()
.ButtonType(GridButtonType.ImageAndText))
.DataBinding(dataBinding => dataBinding.Server()
        .Insert("PlayerAdd", "Player", new { })
        .Update("PlayerUpdate", "Player", new { })
        .Delete("PlayerDelete", "Player", new { })
)
.Columns(columns =>
             {
                 columns.Bound(b => b.Name);
                 columns.Bound(b => b.Price);

                 columns.Command(commands =>
                 {                    
                     commands.Edit();
                     commands.Delete();
                 }).Width(200);

             })
.Editable(editing => editing.Mode(GridEditMode.PopUp)))
```

model:

```
public class GamePlayer2
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [DataType(DataType.Currency)]
    public decimal Price{ get; set; }
}
```

Scripts are registered on _Layout. Where is a problem? Why currency(integer,date etc) textbox won't display for fields?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you have added the EditorTemplates under the **Shared/EditorTemplates** folder. Basically they are automatically added if you have used the wizard to create your project. If not create a demo project and copy-paste them from there.

Comment: yes! there is no templates in NuGet package. I  copied it from test project on codeplex.